# Style property causing 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm storing JSX code in a variable

```
const centerStyle = {textAlign: 'center'};
viewState.myContent = (
  <Fragment>
     <p style={centerStyle}>Some text</p>
  </Fragment>
)
```

Later I'm rendering this fragment, which is throwing the error. `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

However, if I remove the style property, the error goes away. Also, if I just render the paragraph without storing it in a variable, there is no error.
It seems like there's a problem with the combination of storing JSX in a variable and using style properties, but I don't know why?

Comment: are you rendering this in a map or loop?

Answer (score 0):

When I simplify your example I don't see any error. Can you update your snippet to cause the error?

```js
const centerStyle = {textAlign: 'center'};

const Test = () => <React.Fragment><p style={centerStyle}>Some text</p></React.Fragment>;

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The key is to store the paragraph tag in a variable and then use the variable to render.

Comment: Updated to store the paragraph in a component. Still no issue. Did you leave any code out? Any loops?